# Improve algorithm execution time

Tags: c#, algorithm, parallel-processing

I am working on Data mining project and I've chosen Apriori algorithm for Association rules task. Briefly saying I am not satisfied with execution time the way I've implemented it. 
I will describe just problematic part of my code.

I have two Lists of lists.

`List<List<int>> one;`

`List<List<int>> two;`

I've to iterate through elements of list `one` and check if `one[i]` is subset of `two[j]`

```
foreach(List<int> items in one)
{

    foreach(List<int> items2 in two)
    {

        if(items2.ContainsSetOf(items1))
        {
            //do something
        }
}
```

I was thinking if there are way to reduce execution time for such apporoach. (Parallel execution, using dictionaries, etc)

Do you guys have any idea how it's possible to reduce it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C# code snippet**

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<List<int>>>();

foreach (List<int> list2 in two) {
   foreach (int i in list2) {
      if(dict.ContainsKey(i) == FALSE) {
         //create empty HashSet dict[i]
         dict.Add(i, new HashSet<List<int>>());
      }
      //add reference to list2 to the HashSet dict[i]
      dict[i].Add(list2); 
   }
}

foreach (List<int> list1 in one) {
   HashSet<List<int>> listsInTwoContainingList1 = null;
   foreach (int i in list1) {
      if (listsInTwoContainingList1 == null) {
         listsInTwoContainingList1 = new HashSet<List<int>>(dict[i]);
      } else {
         listsInTwoContainingList1.IntersectWith(dict[i]);
      }
      if(listsInTwoContainingList1.Count == 0) {   //optimization :p
         break;
      }
   }
   foreach (List<int> list2 in listsInTwoContainingList1) {
      //list2 contains list1
      //do something
   }   
}
```

**Example**

```
L2= {
L2a = {10, 20, 30, 40}
L2b = {30, 40, 50, 60}
L2c = {10, 25, 30, 40}
}

L1 = {
L1a = {10, 30, 40}
L1b = {30, 25, 50}
}
```

After the first part of the code:

```
dict[10] = {L2a, L2c}
dict[20] = {L2a}
dict[25] = {L2c}
dict[30] = {L2a, L2b, L2c}
dict[40] = {L2a, L2b, L2c}
dict[50] = {L2c}
dict[60] = {L2c}
```

In the second part of the code:

```
L1a: dict[10] n dict[30] n dict[40] = {L2a, L2c}
L1b: dict[30] n dict[25] n dict[50] = { }
```

So `L1a` is included in `L2a` and `L2c`, but `L1b` in none.

**Complexity**

Now regarding the algorithm complexity, suppose `L1` has `n1` elements, `L2` has `n2` elements, the average number of elements of the sublists of `L1` is `m1` and the average number of elements of the sublists of `L2` is `m2`. Then:

- the original solution is:
  `O(n1 x n2 x m1 x m2)`, if the *containsSetOf* method does a nested loop, or, at best, `O(n1 x n2 x (m1 + m2))`, if it uses a HashSet. Is7aq's solution is also `O(n1 x n2 x (m1 + m2))`.
- the proposed solution is:
  `O(n2 x m2 + n1 x (m1 x nd + n2))`, where `nd` is the average number of elements of the sets `dict[i]`.

The efficiency of the proposed solution depends a lot on this `nd`:

- If `nd` is large - close to `n2` (when every integer is part of every sublist of `L2`), then it is just as slow as the original one.
- However, if `nd` is expected to be small (i.e. the sublists of `L2` are quite different from one another), then the proposed solution would typically be much faster, especially if `n1` and `n2` are large.

Answer (score 4):

Make them lists of sets, and use set operations to find if a set of subset of another.

**Example**

```
HashSet<int> set1 = new HashSet<int>();
set1.Add(1);
set1.Add(2);

HashSet<int> set2 = new HashSet<int>();
set2.Add(1);
set2.Add(2);
set2.Add(3);

List<HashSet<int>> one = new List<HashSet<int>>();
one.add(set1);
one.add(set2);

List<HashSet<int>> two = new List<HashSet<int>>();
two.add(set1);
two.add(set2);

foreach(Set<int> setA in one) {
    foreach(Set<int> setB in two) {
        if(setA.IsSubsetOf(setB)) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can use `IsSubSet()` method, but problem is not here. But I still have to compare every element with another which is N^2. Maybe I understand wrong your solution. Could you provide code example?

Comment: @JohnLatham: Having two `List<HashSet<T>>` will improve the execution time. Subset is much cheaper on proper sets than lists. You can also consider using indexing.

Comment: @Ibrahim, Thanks, do you know how much times iteration approximately should be faster?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the number of iterations is the same as before because the requirement is to compare all sets in `one` to all sets in `two`, but you gain speed in the check itself because sets are implemented in a way to make the `subset` test more efficient. Having said that, there is probably room to make the number of iterations less than `n^2`, but that's hard to know without giving more details about the problem and the nature of the data stored in the sets.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce the number of checks "Is list in list" (or is set a subset), one way is to build a hierarchy (tree) of lists. Of course, the performance improvement (if any) depends on the data - if none of the lists contain other lists, you will have to do all checks as now.

Comment: Thank you, Igor. I was thinking about something similar. But still had hope that its possible to make it in O(N) time.